# JSON Parsing to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking for approach.

I am parsing in JSON which is returning data in form

```
UserA  PhotoURL1  
UserA  PhotoURL2
UserB  PhotoURL3
UserA  PhotoURL4
UserB  PhotoURL5
UserA  PhotoURL6
```

I need to store it in My Custom Array List

```
String name,
List<Photo> photos
```

So result should be

```
UserA   Photo1 
        Photo2
        Photo4
        Photo6

UserB   Photo3
        Photo5
```

What approach should I take? Please help

Comment: What does your JSON look like exactly? What JSON library do you use, if any?

Comment: What code have you already written?

Comment: apart from the two comments above, you show us that you are not expecting  an ArrayList, but a Map..

Comment: Hi , Parsing of JSON is not an issue for me. To store data in correct data structure is the issue. Kent , Do you think i need a map to store and dispaly data in this form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Populating a map (as @Kent suggests) from the given data is usually done using something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Photo>> result = new HashMap<String, List<Photo>>();

while(data.hasMoreData()) {

  String name = data.getName();
  String photo = data.getPhoto();

  List<Photo> photos = result.get(name);
  if (photos == null) {
    photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    result.put(name, photos);
  }
  photos.add(photo);

}

System.out.println(result);
```

In any event we would need to understand how the original data is json formatted to do this.

Comment: Thanks , I am trying your answer.

Comment: You saved my day. You are genious. Hats off to you.